# How can i nest column validation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, validation, conditional

How can I nest column validation

```
=IF(OR(
    [Position]="Ground Support Equipment - Ramp Equipment Operator (GSE-REO)",
    [Position]="Ramp Equipment Operator (REO)",
    [Position]="Cargo Checker",
    [Position]="Cargo - Ramp Equipment Operator (Cargo - REO)",
    [Position]="Fuel Operations Helper",
    [Position]="Warehouse Helper"
),IF(OR(
    [PPE - Safety Shoes Size]="N/A",
    [PPE - Rainboots Size]="N/A",
    [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A",
    [PPE- Raincoat Size]="N/A"
    ),FALSE,TRUE),<insertIF>)
==============================================
=IF(OR(
    [Position]="Loader / Ramp Loader",
    [Position]="Catering Driver",
    [Position]="Catering Helper",
    [Position]="Cargo Loader",
    [Position]="Technical Supply Helper",
    [Position]="Cargo Worker"
),IF(OR(
    [PPE - Safety Shoes Size]="N/A",
    [PPE - Rainboots Size]="N/A",
    [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A",
    [PPE- Raincoat Size]="N/A",
    [PPE - Back Support Size]="N/A"
    ),FALSE,TRUE),<insertIF>) 
============================================
=IF([Position]="Crewing Driver",
    IF([PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A",FALSE,TRUE)
    ,<PASS>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the nested validation formula:

```
IF(
    OR(
        [Position]="Ground Support Equipment - Ramp Equipment Operator (GSE-REO)",
        [Position]="Ramp Equipment Operator (REO)", [Position]="Cargo Checker", 
        [Position]="Cargo - Ramp Equipment Operator (Cargo - REO)", 
        [Position]="Fuel Operations Helper", 
        [Position]="Warehouse Helper" 
    ),
    IF(
        OR( 
            [PPE - Safety Shoes Size]="N/A", 
            [PPE - Rainboots Size]="N/A", 
            [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A", 
            [PPE- Raincoat Size]="N/A"
        ),
    FALSE,TRUE),
    IF(
        OR(
            [Position]="Loader / Ramp Loader", 
            [Position]="Catering Driver", 
            [Position]="Catering Helper", 
            [Position]="Cargo Loader", 
            [Position]="Technical Supply Helper", 
            [Position]="Cargo Worker" 
        ),
        IF(
            OR( 
                [PPE - Safety Shoes Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE - Rainboots Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE- Raincoat Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE - Back Support Size]="N/A"
            ),
        FALSE,TRUE),
        IF(
            AND(
            [Position]="Crewing Driver",
            [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A"
            ), 
        FALSE, TRUE
        )
    )
)
```

**However** it reaches the length limit. We need to **rewrite** the formula and **shorten** the length.

**Workaround:**

Create a calculated column as the flag to verify part of column values.

In this test, I create a calculated named "test" with the following formula:

```
IF(
    OR(
        [Position]="Ground Support Equipment - Ramp Equipment Operator (GSE-REO)",
        [Position]="Ramp Equipment Operator (REO)", [Position]="Cargo Checker", 
        [Position]="Cargo - Ramp Equipment Operator (Cargo - REO)", 
        [Position]="Fuel Operations Helper", 
        [Position]="Warehouse Helper" 
    ),
    IF(
        OR( 
            [PPE - Safety Shoes Size]="N/A", 
            [PPE - Rainboots Size]="N/A", 
            [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A", 
            [PPE- Raincoat Size]="N/A"
        ),
    "No","Yes"),
    IF(
        OR(
            [Position]="Loader / Ramp Loader", 
            [Position]="Catering Driver", 
            [Position]="Catering Helper", 
            [Position]="Cargo Loader", 
            [Position]="Technical Supply Helper", 
            [Position]="Cargo Worker" 
        ),
        IF(
            OR( 
                [PPE - Safety Shoes Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE - Rainboots Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE- Raincoat Size]="N/A", 
                [PPE - Back Support Size]="N/A"
            ),
        "No","Yes"),"None"
    )
)
```

[image]

Then, enter the formula below as the validation formula:

```
IF([test]="None",
    IF(
        [Position]="Crewing Driver", 
        IF(
            [PPE - Safety Vest Size]="N/A",
        FALSE,TRUE),
    ),
    IF([test]="No",FALSE,TRUE)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Great Explanation ♥